# OCamlのulexの使い方を教えてください

Tags: ocaml

OCamlでUnicodeを扱うパーサを作る為にulexを使う事を考えています。
例えば、以下のような四則演算のパーサがあります。

parser.mly

```
%{
%}

%token <int> INT
%token ADD SUB MUL DIV EOF
%left ADD SUB
%left MUL DIV
%type <int> exp
%start exp

%%

exp:
| INT         { $1 }
| exp ADD exp { $1 + $3 }
| exp SUB exp { $1 - $3 }
| exp MUL exp { $1 * $3 }
| exp DIV exp { $1 / $3 }
```

lexer.mll

```
{
open Parser
}

rule token = parse
| [' ' '\t' '\n' '\r']+ { token lexbuf }
| ['0'-'9']+ { INT(int_of_string (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf)) }
| '-' { SUB }
| '+' { ADD }
| '*' { MUL }
| eof { EOF }
| _ { assert false }
```

main.ml

```
let _ =
  let lexbuf = Lexing.from_string "1+2*3" in
  let result = Parser.exp Lexer.token lexbuf in
  Printf.printf "%d\n" result
```

Makefile

```
main: parser.ml lexer.ml main.ml
    ocamlfind ocamlc -package ulex parser.mli parser.ml lexer.ml main.ml -o main
parser.ml: parser.mly
    ocamlyacc parser.mly
lexer.ml: lexer.mll
    ocamllex lexer.mll
clean:
    rm -rf *.cm* parser.ml lexer.ml main *.o
```

opamのリポジトリを検索したところ

./4.02.1/lib/ulex/ulexing.mli
./4.02.1/lib/ulex/utf8.mli

の２つが参考になりそうでした。

> They need not work on a type named [lexbuf]: you can use the type
>   name you want. Then, just do in your ulex-processed source, before
>   the first lexer specification:
>
> [module Ulexing = L]
>
> Of course, you'll probably want to define functions like [lexeme]
>   to be used in the lexers semantic actions.

と書いてあるのでlexer.mllに`module Ulexing = L`と書くと良いようなので、、、。

lexer.mllを以下のように書き換えればコンパイルは通りました。

```
{
open Parser
module Ulexing = Lexing
}

rule token = parse
| [' ' '\t' '\n' '\r']+ { token lexbuf }
| ['0'-'9']+ { INT(int_of_string (Ulexing.lexeme lexbuf)) }
| '-' { SUB }
| '+' { ADD }
| '*' { MUL }
| eof { EOF }
| _ { assert false }
```

しかし、これでは単に名前を書き換えているだけに思えますし、LというLexerはありません。
このような使い方で良いのか良くわからないのと、やりたい事としては、ocamllex上でutf-8を扱えるようにしたいのですが、ulexのありがたみが良くわかりません。

https://twitter.com/takeisa/status/503531375127838720

Webで調べたところ上記のような事が書いてありました。

このあと自分で調べるとなると、mliの内容を翻訳してみればよいと思うのですが、分かりやすいサンプルなどがあれば教えてください。

Comment: どう使おうとされて、どううまく行かなかったのか、説明してください。何で困っておられるのかわからない限り、 README を読んでください、という以上のお答えしかできません。

Comment: 質問内容を変更しました。具体的にはScalaのパーサを作っていてUTF-8対応したいのですが、この例だと例えば'+'を'＋'に書き換えて使えるようにしたり、文字コード指定での範囲指定をしたいのです。

Comment: READMEはこれで、
https://github.com/whitequark/ulex/blob/master/README
例は
https://github.com/fferreira/LogicParser
みたいですね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ulex は ocamllex 使った字句解析手法ではありません。質問の例では lexer.mll を ocamllex で処理しているので ulex を全く使っていません。

Ulex は .ml に直接字句解析ルールを書くためのライブラリです。 ocamllex や他の字句解析ツールに存在するルール記述のためのDSLは ulex では pa_ulex.cma という CamlP4 文法拡張として提供されています:

```
lexer
    R1 -> e1
  | R2 -> e2
    ...
  | Rn -> en
```

これは ocamllex での

```
parse
  | R1 { e1 }
  | R2 { e2 }
    ...
  | Rn { en }
```

に相当するものですが、 `lexer R1 -> e1 | .. | Rn -> en` は pa_ulex.cma によって普通の OCaml の式に展開されるので、普通に `let` で束縛する事ができます。Ulex での

```
let rule1 = lexer R1 -> e1 | ... | Rn -> en
```

は ocamllex での

```
rule rule1 = parse R1 { e1 } | ... | Rn { en }
```

に大体一致します。

概要は以上です。詳しくは README および Ulex を使っている例をビルドしてみて、 pa_ulex.cma が実際にどうこの拡張文法を含む .ml ファイルのプリプロセスに使われているかを確認してください。